# Derivative of modulus function $|\tan x| + |\sec x|$ at $x = \frac{5\pi}{6}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

> Find the derivative of $|\tan x| + |\sec x|$ at $x = \dfrac{5\pi}{6}$.

I'm really having some hard time solving these type of derivative questions involving modulus functions. I tried solving but not sure if It is a good method.

---

**Here's how I tried this:**

Since derivative of $|x| = \dfrac{x}{|x|}$,

Derivative of $|\tan x|  + |\sec x| = \dfrac{\tan x}{|\tan x|}\cdot \sec^2{x} + \dfrac{\sec x}{|\sec x|} \cdot \sec{x}\cdot\tan x =\tan x\sec^2{x}\left[\dfrac{1}{|\tan x|} +\dfrac{1}{|\sec x|} \right]$

Substituting $x= \dfrac{5\pi}{6}$
$$\tan (\frac{5\pi}{6})\sec^2{(\frac{5\pi}{6})}\left[\dfrac{1}{|\tan (\frac{5\pi}{6})|} +\dfrac{1}{|\sec (\frac{5\pi}{6})|} \right]$$
$$\implies\tan (\pi - \frac{\pi}{6})\sec^2{(\pi - \frac{\pi}{6})}\left[\dfrac{1}{|\tan (\pi - \frac{\pi}{6})|} +\dfrac{1}{|\sec (\pi - \frac{\pi}{6})|} \right]$$
$$\implies-\tan (\frac{\pi}{6})\sec^2{(\frac{\pi}{6})}\left[\dfrac{1}{|\tan (\frac{\pi}{6})|} +\dfrac{1}{|\sec (\frac{\pi}{6})|} \right]$$
$$\implies- \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Big){\Big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\Big)^2}\left[\dfrac{1}{|\tan (\frac{1}{\sqrt3})|} +\dfrac{1}{|\sec (\frac{2}{\sqrt3})|} \right]$$
$$\implies- \Big(\frac{4}{3\sqrt{3}}\Big)\left[\sqrt3+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]$$
$$\implies- \Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big)\left[1+\dfrac{1}{2} \right]$$
$$\implies- \Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big)\left[\dfrac{3}{2} \right]$$
$$\implies-2$$

---

I'm wondering if there are some more good methods which are short/easy.

Thanks for your time! :D

Comment: Note that $\left| {\tan x} \right| + \left| {\sec x} \right| =  - \tan x - \sec x$ near $x=5\pi/6$. Since the derivative is a local thing, you can assume that you are differentiating $- \tan x - \sec x$ at $x=5\pi/6$.

Comment: Thank you @Gary, that's really new for me :O

Comment: @gary how can that equivalence be derived? or why is it that all the combinations of ±tanx ± secx wil cover all of |tanx| + |secx|

Comment: @user29418 The question is to determine the derivative of $|\tan x|+|\sec x|$ at $x=5\pi/6$. When computing the derivative at a point, you consider the function near that point (remember the definition). But in a small neighbourhood of $x=5\pi/6$, $|\tan x|+|\sec x|$ agrees with $-\tan x-\sec x$ since both $\tan x$ and $\sec x$ are negative near $x=5\pi/6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\left(\frac\pi2,\pi\right)$, you always have $\tan x<0$ and $\sec x<0$. So, in that interval you have that, if $f(x)=|\tan x|+|\sec x|$, then $f(x)=-\tan(x)-\sec(x)$, and so$$f'(x)=-\sec^2(x)-\tan(x)\sec(x).$$This simplifies the computations.